# Easy way to trace hardware events in Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-8

My Windows machine is acting kind of funny.  Every once in a while the screen gets really laggy, as does the sound, and a bunch of device connected/device disconnected sounds start firing.  This happens for about fifteen seconds then all returns to normal.

I am thinking some hardware is failing, but I don't know what.  It sounds like something is turning off/on or rebooting or just failing or whatever.  I figure the best way to find out is to trace those connect/disconnect events, but I can't figure out how.

The system log in Event Viewer is of no. Help.  Any other ideas?